# Проблема с pathinfo()

Tags: php

Всем привет!
Заметил такую особенность, есть клевая функция, pathinfo и вот от нее можно получить имя файла без расширения:

```
$str = pathinfo('Новый файл.jpg', PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

И выводит все это дело вот через var_dump(), вот такую красоту:

> string(9) " файл"

Главное, количество символов правильно увидел, 9. А вот первое слово с кириллицы выкидывает. Баг?

Comment: Это не количество символов, это количество байт.

Comment: А ОС какая? И php какое? Откуда вызываете (cli, апач/nginx)? И с чего это кол-во символов правильное? "Новый файл" - 10 символов, а не 9. 9 - это кол-во байт, т.е. для русских букв по два байта используются, + 1 для пробела.

Comment: **System:** Linux toptomsk.ru 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 22 17:26:33 UTC 2012 x86_64  **Apache Version**: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) **PHP Version**: 5.3.3-7

Answer (score 8):

[pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php) использует текущие настройки локали. Поэтому для корректной работы при использовании многобайтных кодировок необходимо явно устанавливать локаль через [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setlocale.php):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.utf8');

$str = pathinfo('Новый файл.jpg', PATHINFO_FILENAME);
var_dump($str); // string(19) "Новый файл"
```

**UPD:** сработает только если соответствующая локаль установлена в системе.

Посмотреть список установленных локалей можно так:

```
locale -a
```

Если нужной локали в списке нет, то и установить ее не получится, следовательно и работать это не будет.

Проверить корректность установки локали можно через возвращаемое значение, если `setlocale` вернет `false`, то установить локаль не получилось.

Comment: При этом в консоли у меня все работало и без локали.

Comment: Ого, спасибо. Действительно причина в этом была.